# How to use OR function with FIND in Excel

Tags: excel, find, gis, geocoding

I'm trying to clean a column of addresses (`Column J`) for geocoding in ArcMap. To clean the specific column of addresses I have, I need to remove excess characters that come after the address. For example, I'm trying to reduce

```
1053 COLEMAN RD BLDG # 1
```

to

```
1053 COLEMAN RD
```

To do so I've attempted using:

```
=LEFT(J2,FIND(" DR ",J2)+3)
```

How do I use an `OR` function to include other strings such as " ST " or " RD "?

Answer (score 0):

use AGGREGATE to iterate the array:

```
=LEFT(J2,AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({" DR "," ST "," RD "},J2)+3,1))
```

[image]